# Get byte from the Android camera

Tags: android, video, camera, chat

I want to make an app with **video chat** and this need to get **real-time bytes of camera** and *send through a socket*. I have no idea how to get these bytes without having to save the video on mobile. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [`SurfaceTexture`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) API that you can specify as an output for an Android Camera and access frames directly there. Best of luck!